# How do I get a combo box in Access to have a numerical value output?

Tags: database, ms-access

Not sure if I am asking this question correctly because I am fairly new to Access and databases.

I have 3 tables and 3 forms so far that are somewhat complete and I am trying to get them to work together but this step is a little furth down the road from where I am now.

At this point, I am working on a shipping form that looks like this:
[image]

Now from here I have this 'combo' box for shipping fees with nothing in it.

To keep it simple, lets say I want to add two choices:

> USPS Priority $5.75
>
> USPS Express $19.95

How can I add this to my combo box but still get it to output it as 5.75 or 19.95 for the purpose of calculating the shipping charge in with the order?

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick thought and let me know if it helps? The data in your table should be in a combo box with two columns. The first column takes your $amounts. The second takes their definition. The value is taken from column1 so you can process that in your database.

Comment: I think you're probably right but I'm such a novice at this and no real help other than here and Access for Dummies. Lol  I did make a small table to house the method and price and then linked it to the Row Source for the shipping field. 2 columns, 1st column bound. I am assuming that the price is hidden from plain view. The data in the field shows up so I am assuming I just need to write a function to add that shipping method to the total (instead of a price because it isn't a numerical value)

Comment: Go into your table in Design Mode. The field for price needs to be data type: number, Field Size: Double, Decimalplaces: 2. On the lookup tab change Display Control to Combo Box, Row Source Type Value List, Bound Column 1, Column Count 2, Column widths sufficient to show the price and its description, List width the sum of the above two widths.    A separate field for things like 'USPS Priority' is not needed. That text goes in the Price field. Also the price is not hidden. You will see a two-coluumn list - price and its description. It's a numerical field so you can do things like Sum etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set your combo box property:

1. Record Source = SELECT Method, Rate FROM tb_Shipping (assume you have table tb_shipping)
2. Column Count = 2
3. Bound Column = 1 (0 is the first column and 1 is the second column which is rate)
4. Column width = x";0" (x is your combox box width)

You can get rate from me.combobox.value (method is me.combobox.column(0))

Comment: I think I got this to work but I had to do it slightly different. There was no Record Source so I used Row Source and added a mini query to tb_shipping. I didn't quite understand the last part of me.combobox.column(0).

Comment: If you have multiple columns on the record source, for example it is two on my example, you can retrieve data of each column by using me.combobox.column(x).  X starts from 0 for the first column.